# Is there BETWEEN DateTime in C# just like SQL does?

Tags: c#

Is there between DateTime in C# ? I know I can do simple check with `if (a > date1 && a < date2)` but I was trying to find `Between` method.

Comment: Between in SQL is inclusive, your example is exclusive.

Comment: I suspect the .net framework team punted on providing a helper due to the combinations of inclusive and exclusive on either end.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

There is not a `Between` function but should be easy enough to add one

```
public static bool Between(DateTime input, DateTime date1, DateTime date2)
{
    return (input > date1 && input < date2);
}
```

Comment: It would be better to make such function the extension method.

Comment: `public static bool IsBetween(this DateTime input, DateTime date1, DateTime date2) { return (input >= date1 && input <= date2); }` i guess this could be bit nicer :-)

Comment: It should be noted that the SQL Between statement translates to `Value >= date1 And Value <= date2`. I.e., it is inclusive of the endpoints (one of the reasons I'm not fond of SQL's between is exactly for this reason: it isn't obvious).

Answer (score 55):

Why restrict to just dates, use the [`IComparable` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx).

```
public static bool InclusiveBetween (this IComparable a, IComparable b, IComparable c)
{
    return a.CompareTo(b) >= 0 && a.CompareTo(c) <= 0;
}

public static bool ExclusiveBetween (this IComparable a, IComparable b, IComparable c)
{
    return a.CompareTo(b) > 0 && a.CompareTo(c) < 0;
}

public static bool SqlBetween (this IComparable a, IComparable b, IComparable c)
{
    return a.InclusiveBetween(b, c);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't compile, Add a ( at the beggining of return and the end ;

Answer (score 19):

No, there is not.

Comment: I would have added a function like everyone else did, but the question included valid code already.  It seemed redundant.  Cheers!

Answer (score 7):

FWIW, BETWEEN is inclusive, not exclusive WRT to its bounds. Anyway, here you go:

```
public static bool Between(this DateTime instant, DateTime dtFrom , DateTime dtThru )
{
  if (dtFrom > dtThru) throw new ArgumentException( "dtFrom may not be after dtThru", "dtFrom" );
  bool isBetween = ( instant >= dtFrom && instant <= dtThru );
  return isBetween;
}
```

Comment: Why assign the value to isBetween instead of just returning it?  But I have to give you props for being the first person to realize Between is inclusive.

Comment: Facilitates debugging/logging (not that this should require a lot of either, but it's good to try and set an example for doing things the Right Way).

Answer (score 5):

Building on @richardschneider answer, my solution adds a boundary range type as a parameter.

```
public enum RangeBoundaryType
{
    [Description("Exclusive")]
    Exclusive,

    [Description("Inclusive on both boundaries")]
    Inclusive,

    [Description("Inclusive on only the lower boundary")]
    InclusiveLowerBoundaryOnly,

    [Description("Inclusive on only the upper boundary")]
    InclusiveUpperBoundaryOnly
}

public static bool Between(this IComparable value, IComparable comparator0, IComparable comparator1, RangeBoundaryType rangeBoundary)
{
    switch (rangeBoundary)
    {
        case RangeBoundaryType.Exclusive:
            return (value.CompareTo(comparator0) > 0 && value.CompareTo(comparator1) < 0);

        case RangeBoundaryType.Inclusive:
            return (value.CompareTo(comparator0) >= 0 && value.CompareTo(comparator1) <= 0);

        case RangeBoundaryType.InclusiveLowerBoundaryOnly:
            return (value.CompareTo(comparator0) >= 0 && value.CompareTo(comparator1) < 0);

        case RangeBoundaryType.InclusiveUpperBoundaryOnly:
            return (value.CompareTo(comparator0) > 0 && value.CompareTo(comparator1) <= 0);

        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This way is fast and the parameters are reversible:

```
public static bool BetweenInclusive(this DateTime value, DateTime a, DateTime b)
{
    return ((a <= value) && (value <= b)) || ((b <= value) && (value <= a));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add an extension method :

```
public static Boolean Between(this DateTime input, DateTime minDate, DateTime maxDate)
{
    // SQL takes limit in !
    return input >= minDate && input <= maxDate;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I use something similar to [Richard Schneider's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5709217/921690) (universal between)  and [Gary Pendlebury's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28857242/921690) (simpler configurable boundary inclusion)

```
public static bool Between(this IComparable value, IComparable lowerBoundary, IComparable upperBoundary, 
    bool includeLowerBoundary=true, bool includeUpperBoundary=true)
{
    var lower = value.CompareTo(lowerBoundary);
    var upper = value.CompareTo(upperBoundary);
    return (lower > 0 || (includeLowerBoundary && lower == 0)) &&
           (upper < 0 || (includeUpperBoundary && upper == 0));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is not, but if you obey number line formatting per [Code Complete](http://books.google.com/books?ei=NausTYysNOiO0QGQs835CA&ct=result&id=QnghAQAAIAAJ&dq=code%20complete&q=number-line%20order#search_anchor), the raw code looks simpler:

```
if((lowDate < a) && (a < highDate))
```

Answer (score 2):

My version (build on @richardschneider answer) with parametrized inclusivity:

```
public static bool IsBetween(this IComparable value, IComparable lower, IComparable upper, bool isInclusive = true)
    {
        if (isInclusive)
        {
            return value.CompareTo(lower) >= 0 && value.CompareTo(upper) <= 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return value.CompareTo(lower) > 0 && value.CompareTo(upper) < 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31848994)