# Regex between two times

Tags: c#, regex

I have a file with a few million lines in them.

Every line starts like this:

```
2016/04/05 11:20:43.293
```

I would like a regex (or other option?) to get all the lines that fall between two times. (for example between 11:20 and 11:25)

Also, if it's possible to match one or more words in those lines, that would be helpfull as well. However, perhaps a regex isn't the best way to go then?

Comment: You have to add more samples to your question.

Comment: You should describe a little more what you are trying to achieve. Give an example of a few lines of input and few lines of expected output.

Comment: You think regex is your best solution? Your usecase isn't exactly the problem regex was created to solve. What you are trying to accomplish can be done so much better using very simple scripting.

Comment: Matching words is easy, matching a date and time within a given range is next to impossible, or horribly inefficient at best. You're better off parsing into a DateTime object and doing your comparison that way. That's a much better and more suitable way of accomplishing this than regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `DateTime.TryParseExact` and `File.ReadLines` with this LINQ query:

```
string format = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.fff";
DateTime dt;
var relevantLines = File.ReadLines(path)
    .Where(l => l.Length >= format.Length
        && DateTime.TryParseExact(l.Substring(0, format.Length), format, DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt)
        && dt.TimeOfDay >= start && dt.TimeOfDay <= end);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to use a Regex:

```
Regex TimePattern = new Regex("\\d{2}:\\d{2}.\\d{3}");
```

Parse the matches to datetime and check if the time is valid:

```
foreach (Match M in TimePattern.Matches(FILECONTENT))
{
  DateTime Dt = Convert.ToDateTime(M.groups[1]));
  //Now you can check if the time "Dt" is between 11:20 and 11:25
}
```

To compare the time you could use (like described in [Is there BETWEEN DateTime in C# just like SQL does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708986/is-there-between-datetime-in-c-sharp-just-like-sql-does)):

```
public static bool Between(DateTime input, DateTime date1, DateTime date2)
{
    return (input > date1 && input < date2);
}
```