# Get time from datetime

Tags: c#, datetime

i have this code to read the first and the last datetime from a log file.
It's correct.

For example,  `logDates.First() = 2017-06-03 15:58:45` `logDates.Last() = 2017-06-03 16:05:00`

```
List<DateTime> logDates = new List<DateTime>();

            //Define regex string
            string pattern = @"(?<logDate>(\d){4}-(\d){2}-(\d){2}\s(\d){2}:(\d){2}:(\d){2})";
            Regex reg = new Regex(pattern);

            //read log content
            string logContent = File.ReadAllText("test.log");

            //run regex
            MatchCollection matches = reg.Matches(logContent);


            //iterate over matches
            foreach (Match m in matches)
            {
                DateTime logTime = DateTime.Parse(m.Groups["logDate"].Value);
                logDates.Add(logTime);
            }

            //show first and last entry
            Console.WriteLine("First: " + logDates.First());
            Console.WriteLine("Last: " + logDates.Last());
```

Now, i would two `Datetime first;` `Datetime second;` only with 15:58:45 (first), 16:05:00 (second).

is it possible?

I would to compare these dates (first and last) with another two dates (obtained from input console) and check if the range is correct.

Regards,
Nonac

Comment: Do you mean 1st and 2nd entry?

Comment: Kindly edit the question.  What would you like to do with the dates?

Comment: Just use a format string: `date.ToString("hh:mm:ss")`

Comment: @zoho_deployment now i hope to be clear

Comment: @nonac I'm afraid you've only made it worse. Are you planning on comparing string representations of time-of-day values? Could you add a simple example on what the input and expected output of the comparison is?

Comment: DateTime can compare itself as DateTime. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @jmag Yes, i would to do this. but the dates (obtained from input console), they don't have the date inside, only the time

Comment: @nonac this should help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708986/is-there-between-datetime-in-c-sharp-just-like-sql-does  as of the input as containing only the timestamp, it would be better to input the date too. If not possible to have date then I have to ask is the time from current day?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `TimeOfDay` property of `DateTime` to get a `TimeSpan` object, which you can compare.

```
DateTime first = DateTime.Parse("2017-06-03 15:58:45");
DateTime second = DateTime.Parse("2017-06-03 16:05:00");

TimeSpan firstTimeOnly = first.TimeOfDay;
TimeSpan secondTimeOnly = second.TimeOfDay;

bool firstBeforeSecond = firstTimeOnly < secondTimeOnly; // true
bool firstEqualsSecond = firstTimeOnly == secondTimeOnly; // false
```

[.net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/f2Wfde)